# Distributed two-steps transaction including EF and web service call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, distributed

I have a 'M' manager (conductor) instance, which controls two other instances 'A' and 'B'. 'A' is az Entity Framework data saver, 'B' calls an external web service to do something. The code of 'M' looks like:

```
// code inside 'M'
void Save()
  B.Save()
  A.Save()
```

This is a kind of distributed transaction. When B.Save drops exception, then A.Save should not happen or finish. Now I have to change it to works well. The problem is, that 'M' does not know anything about how an EF transaction works, or how to handle it, and A.Save cannot include the B.Save call. So I have to change it to somehow:

```
Object transaction = A.PrepareSave()
try {      
     B.Save() 
}
catch { 
     A.RollbackSave(transaction) 
     throw
}
A.FinishSave(transaction)
```

Where the A.PrepareSave() looks like (?)

```
TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()
var context = CreateContext()
... do something EF ...
context.SaveChanges(false)
return new MyCustomTuple(scope,context)
```

And where A.FinishShave(Object trans) look as (?)

```
MyCustomTuple tuple = (MyCustomTuple)trans
TransactionScope scope = (TransactionScope)tuple.Scope
EFContext context = (EFContext)tuple.Context
scope.Complete()
context.AcceptAllChanges()
```

Question 1: is it ok? Is it the way to handle such a situation? (I have no influence on B.Save(), it saves or drops exception)

Question 2: how to free the resources (scope, context) at the end? The 'M' manager does not know anything about the MyCustomTuple and its contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `TransactionScope` right in the M method, you don't need to handle it in different parts of your code.

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
  A.Save();
  B.Save();
  transaction.Complete();
}
```

This will complete if both save methods complete, otherwise an exception is thrown, no call to `Complete()` is made, so there is no commit. The `using` block will free the `TransactionScope`. As for disposing other resources, you can just do it the same way you're doing it now. You have not included any examples for this (I'd expect that the component that creates the context, maybe component A, handles the disposition of that context),

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot.